# Can two sites use the same channel, but have unique entries?

Tags: craft3, multi-site, channels

I have a multi-site application where my primary site is my company's main website, and the additional sites are small "microsites" for some of our projects.

I want to share channels between my sites. For example, I have a "testimonials" channel with a basic quote & cite fields in the entry type.

I want to make this channel available to all my sites, but I want each site's testimonials to be unique, since they're about different projects. I also don't have the same number of testimonials for each site.

I made the channel available to each site, then created the testimonial entries within each site's tab. I thought this would keep each site's testimonial entry list separate, but it instead made one big list.

Is there a way that I can do this through filtering or site groups? I don't want to have to create a unique channel for each site that has the exact same functionality.

Edit: I've found that I can fudge this by using the "Enable for this site" lightswitch on each entry, but I don't trust my content editors to properly use this function, and I don't want them to have to see all the disabled entries from other sites in the entry list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a light switch field in your section settings with the label "propagate entries across all sites". Just turn it off and your entries will be unique

Comment: Note that this setting is only available to Channel sections. With the upcoming 3.1 release, it'll be available for Structures too.